# How to the reload page until element becomes available using Ruby/Capybara?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

**Task:** I am writing a script using Ruby and Capybara that checks if a day in a calendar has become available for booking.

**Problem:** Whenever Capybara can't find this element it throughs an error an everything stops. Below is the line of code that I am using to check if the element is available or not. It return true if is found but throughs and error if it can't find.

```
page.should have_selector("input[type=submit][value='22']")
```

**Question:** How can I keep on refreshing the page until this element is available?

```
Btw: I am using page.driver.browser.navigate.refresh to refresh the page
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using have_selector which raises an error on failure, you can use

```
page.has_selector?("input...")
```

which will return true if the element exists on the page within Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds (pass :wait option to change that time), false otherwise.

Comment: Tom your solution worked for me. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Write a `wait_until` function use it to wait until the element presents on the page. See below:

```
def wait_until
 require "timeout"
 Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
    sleep(0.1) until value = yield
    value
 end
end
```

to call it:

```
wait_until { find(:css, "input[type=submit][value='22']").visible? }
# write your case
```

Comment: This wait_until method does nothing when used with #find because #find already does essentially the same thing internally for up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds so the timeout will never actually retry anything.  Additionally #find will raise an exception if the element is not found within that time so even if the timeout in the wait_until method was longer than default_max_wait_time it would be exited by the exception.

Comment: By default Capybara only finds visible elements so calling `visible?` on the result of that find will always return true (or raise an exception if the element is not visible on the page) - so it won't make anything work -- The example you have given of calling wait_until is identical in behavior to just calling  `find(:css, "input[type=submit][value='22']").visible?` without using the wait_until method at all

Comment: @TomWalpole No if it is not visible it returns false tries again until timeout or visible.

Comment: That would only be true if you passed visible: false as an option to `find` to make it find both visible and non-visible elements - and still wouldn't work if the element was not actually on the page at all since then find would raise an exception - and still the behavior would be the same as just calling `find(:css, "input[type=submit][value='22']")` without using wait_until since find will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for the element to become visible on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The default Capybara behaviour is to wait some time (it's customizable) if it does not find the element.

I suggest you to check your code and your selector.

From https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara:

> When working with asynchronous JavaScript, you might come across situations where you are attempting to interact with an element which is not yet present on the page. Capybara automatically deals with this by waiting for elements to appear on the page.

Comment: It doesn't find the element because it will be available only at a certain time which explains why I need to refresh the page. I will have a look on what u send. Thanks